# Automatic code listing indentation for Java

Tags: formatting, listings, indentation, code, java

I'm a newbie to LaTeX, so sorry if it's a trivial question, but I couldn't find the answer. I'm trying to print code listings inside LaTeX, but when I do so LaTeX doesn't keep code indentation from Java source code. I've found `\lstdefineformat` snippet for C language, but I don't know how to modify it for Java source code. Here's the snippet:

```
\lstdefineformat{stand}{
    \{=\newline\string\newline\indent,
    \}=[;]\newline\noindent\string\newline,
    \};=\newline\noindent\string\newline,
    ;=[\ ]\string\space}
```

And I want to modify this snippet to:

1. Insert new line only after ending curly brace which I managed to do just by removing the first line
2. After each starting curly brace the rest of the code should be indented by tab or 4 spaces regarding the code before the starting curly brace.
3. After each keyword `if` if there is no curly braces for that conditional like:

   ```
   if (err)
       res.send(err);
   ```

There also should be indentation for the code after `if` or `else` statements.

Does anyone know how to do that or have a full command to format Java source code in LaTeX. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Where is `\lstdefineformat` defined? Can you please extend your code snippet into a minimal working example?